# How to replace SFSymbol icon transparent color with white color

Tags: ios, swift, sf-symbols

Currently, I am using `CALayer` to achieve ripple effect. However, the transparent color in SFSymbol causes an issue.

I am using the following way to setup `UIImageView`

```
imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "mic.circle.fill")
imageView.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

The above code yield the following outcome. (Green color is `CALayer` with ripple animation)

[image]

---

Instead of transparent color, I would like the mic symbol to have solid white color. I try

```
imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "mic.circle.fill")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

It yields

[image]

Now, I get solid white color for mic symbol. However, the circle no longer solid red color.

---

I further try

```
imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "mic.circle.fill")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal).withTintColor(UIColor.red)
```

[image]

Now, it backs to the same problem again.

Do you have any idea, how can I have a SFSymbol, with

1. Solid white for mic symbol
2. Solid red for the filled circle

Thanks.

Comment: Since your are using that perticular image, you could put a round white image (or view with white background color) behind the mic image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can use the following code snippet

```
    let image = UIImage(
        systemName: "mic.circle.fill",
        withConfiguration:UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(weight: .regular))?.applyingSymbolConfiguration(
            UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(paletteColors:[
                .white,
                .label,
                UIColor(red: 0.90, green: 0.22, blue: 0.21, alpha: 1.00)
            ])
        )
```

This code snippet is generated from 3rd party software: **San Fransymbols**

Answer (score 0):

Add container view, set your imageView to .withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), follow my example below... Set your container and your image view under your class controller:

```
let myImageV: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = UIImage(systemName: "mic.fill")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    iv.tintColor = .white
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    
    return iv
}()

let containerView: UIView = {
    let v = UIView()
    v.backgroundColor = .red
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    v.clipsToBounds = true
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()
```

now in viewDidLoad set constraints

```
view.addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    
    containerView.addSubview(myImageV)
    myImageV.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    myImageV.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    myImageV.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true // here set the height of mic
    myImageV.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true // here set the width of mic
```

This is the result:

[image]